# longtext vertical in textarea rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

index.html.erb doesn't show line break part when the text_area content is to long . . 
example: "Ruby on Rails is a framework that makes it easier to develop, deploy, and
maintain web applications. During the months that followed its initial release,
Rails went from being an unknown toy to being a worldwide phenomenon, and
more important, it has become the framework of choice for the implementation
of a wide range of so-called Web 2.0 applications."
in index.html.erb when showing the textarea , it shows horizontal instead of line break
horizontal: "Ruby on Rails is a framework that makes it easier to develop, deploy, and
maintain"
line break:
 "Ruby on Rails is a framework that makes it easier to develop,
 deploy, and
maintain web applications"

is there any solution to make a line break when the text is to long ?